# converting back the numerical value to alphabetical letters

Tags: batch-file, character, numeric

i found a `batch` .cmd project here that is able to convert the letters to its numerical value, this is it:

```
@echo off

:start

cls

color 9a

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo.

set /p text=(your message) = 

set "code=!text!"

set "chars=0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for /l %%N in (1 1 26) do for /f %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do set "code=!code:%%C=%%N !"

cls

echo.

echo (your message) = !text!

echo.

echo (numeric value) = !code!

echo.

pause

goto :start
```

if i type, "i love you" its numerical value will be "9  12 15 22 5  25 15 21"

what i wanted to do is to reverse the action that if i type a numerical value of something, its corresponding letter or word will appear.

how to do that?

Comment: Wow that's a bad dupe choice @divibisan

Comment: @divibisan there is a slight difference in between `bash` and `batch`.

Comment: @Joshua flagged that comment, because it is obviously not the correct dupe.

Comment: @MartinZeitler @Joshua Sorry about that. I've never heard of `batch` and in the absence of any tags or mention of language, I made a guess at what I was looking at. Glad you caught my mistake. The flag's been retracted and I added a [batch-file] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go backward for reverse

```
@echo off
Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
Set "chars=0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set /p code= input code 
If "!code:~-1!" neq " " set "code=!code! "
for /L %%N in (26 -1 1) do (
  for /f %%C in ("!chars:~%%N, 1!") do set "code=!code:%%N =%%C!"
)
Echo text = !code!
```

Phil